# Why _Map<String, String> is not in [Map<String, String>, bool]

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, types

I need to do runtime type check.

```
void main() {
  final type = [Map<String, String>, bool];
  final mapTest = {"A": "B"};
  if (type.contains(mapTest.runtimeType)) {
    print("yes");
  } else {
    print("no, ${mapTest.runtimeType} is not in $type");
  }
  bool boobool = true;
  if (type.contains(boobool.runtimeType)) {
    print("yes, ${boobool.runtimeType} is in $type");
  } else {
    print("no, ${mapTest.runtimeType} is not in $type");
  }
}
```

`mapTest` should pass the test. But it doesn't. What's wrong ?

```
no, _Map<String, String> is not in {Map<String, String>, bool}
yes, bool is in {Map<String, String>, bool}
```

Comment: Dart create a `Map` with constructor of `_Map` which inherited by `Map`, and you directly mentioned type of `Map<String, String>` in in `type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various answers but I found the simplest solution.

Change

`final type = [Map<String, String>, bool];`

to

`final type = [Map<String, String>().runtimeType, bool];`

It seems to fulfill the purpose

`yes, _Map<String, String> is in [_Map<String, String>, bool, List<String>]`

Comment: Just my opinion, this is an inconsistency in the Dart language. List<String> don't need this hack

Comment: `Map` has this "problem" because it is an abstract class, and it is abstract because it is an interface with multiple possible implementations (`LinkedHashMap`, `SplayTreeMap`). `List<String>` *does* have the same problem on some platforms; with Dart for the Web, `List<String>`'s *concrete* implementation is `JSArray<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Map<K, V>` is an *abstract* type.  It is impossible for any object to have a `runtimeType` of `Map<K, V>`; any object will be an instance of some *concrete* type.
2. `Type` objects usually are equal only for the exact same `Type`; it does not check if one `Type` represents a subtype of the other.

Consequently, it is impossible for `mapTest.runtimeType` to ever compare equal to `Map<K, V>`.

You also will not be able to use `is`; `mapTest is type[0]` is not legal since `is` requires that the right operand be statically known.

At best, for this case, you could check for static types instead of runtime types:

```dart
/// Provides a [staticType] getter on all non-`dynamic` objects.
extension StaticTypeExtension<T> on T {
  /// Returns the static type of this object.
  ///
  /// This can be used to report the static type of an object (which might not
  /// always be obvious due to inference or when dealing with generics), which
  /// might be different from [Object.runtimeType].
  Type get staticType => T;
}

void main() {
  final type = [Map<String, String>, bool];
  final mapTest = {"A": "B"};
  if (type.contains(mapTest.staticType)) {
    print("yes");
  } else {
    print("no, ${mapTest.staticType} is not in $type");
  }
  bool boobool = true;
  if (type.contains(boobool.staticType)) {
    print("yes, ${boobool.staticType} is in $type");
  } else {
    print("no, ${mapTest.staticType} is not in $type");
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
yes
yes, bool is in [Map<String, String>, bool]
```

That said, whatever it is you ultimately want to do with this is probably pretty questionable.  It's usually not a good idea to rely on specific `Type` values because, as mentioned, subtypes won't be automatically handled.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `mapTest's` runtime type is `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>`, which is different from `Map<String, String>` so it fails the type check.

To make the type check pass, you can consider converting the `mapTest` to `Map<String,String` explicitly.

```
final type = [Map<String, String>, bool];
final mapTest = {"A": "B"};
if (type.contains(mapTest.runtimeType) || type.contains(mapTest.runtimeType.toString())) {
  print("yes");
} else if (mapTest is Map<String, String> && type.contains(Map<String, String>)) {
  print("yes, ${mapTest.runtimeType} is in $type");
} else {
  print("no, ${mapTest.runtimeType} is not in $type");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart create a `Map` by using constructor of `_Map` which inherited by class `Map`, and you directly mentioned type of `Map<String, String>` in in `type`.

So I suggest you to go with the way of creating a `runtimeType` in a variable `type`.

```dart
void main() {
  final type = [{"A": "B"} .runtimeType, bool];
  final mapTest = {"A": "B"} as Map<String, String>;
  if (type.contains(mapTest.runtimeType)) {
    print("yes");
  } else {
    print("no, ${mapTest.runtimeType} is not in $type");
  }
  bool boobool = true;
  if (type.contains(boobool.runtimeType)) {
    print("yes, ${boobool.runtimeType} is in $type");
  } else {
    print("no, ${mapTest.runtimeType} is not in $type");
  }
}
```